# start /w not working anymore?

Tags: batch-file, call

I have always used `start /w` in batch files and from a Windows console to run something and pause till the application is closed. But since a few weeks ago, this does not work anymore!

I tried to simply open one by one the `.pdf` files in a folder and it doesn't work. So I studied for at least 3 hours what could be wrong to no avail. And nobody on the Internet seems to mention a problem like that. Today I picked a batch I used in the past to open files in sequence and it doesn't work anymore either. It would use two simple batches, the core one doing just this:

```
cd %1
for %%f in (*.py) do start /wait %%f
cd ..
```

I am pretty sure I used it successfully on the same machine I use now (Win7 Professional, 64-bit). I tried all sorts of things like `call`, `command /b` with the command, but none of them works.

From the console when I do `ver` I get `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]` (from the 32 or the 64-bit console).

What do you think has gone wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! What do you mean exactly by “does not work”? Does it write any error message? Could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi Palec, now I tried again and IT WORKS so I suppose I can close the threat! The example that wasn't working (= was opening all .pdf files without waiting for me to close one by one) was this one, from a command prompt in the same folder as N .pdf files: for %a in (*.pdf) do start /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"  %a

Comment: I think this is a candidate for deletion, it is not going to be useful to anyone. If you close it, it would be automatically deleted after 6 months or so because it has no answers nor upvotes. And I doubt it will get any.

Comment: The pdf works here. Try it in the other bitness cmd.exe to the one you are using.

Comment: @sarahgeen Or if you want help with the `AcroRd32.exe` case, just [edit] your question. It has no answers yet, so even a major shift is OK.

Comment: @sarahgeen By the way, please use `code formatting` (`\`code formatting\``) for commands etc., as is usual around here. It helps others read your posts and comments.

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments, you show that the following specific command fails from the command line:

```
for %a in (*.pdf) do start /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" %a
```

It doesn't work properly because the first argument is treated as a title if it is quoted. If you need to quote your executable, then you must precede the program with a quoted title. You can provide an empty title if you want:

```
for %a in (*.pdf) do start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" %a
```